# Text not marking up

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, markup

I am writing a page which allows a tournament director (TD) to add players to an event. When the TD goes to search for a player I want the search results to appear on keyup below the search input (without needing to refresh the page).
At this stage I have 2 php pages and 1 js page and have the live search happening, but the output is not getting marked up. I have written a piece of code to convert a PHP $_SESSION[''] array to a javascript array, but my brain is frying and I'm not sure where to go from here.

I effectively want the processed version of this code as output (presuming the SQL returns only 1 player named John Smith)

```
<tr></td> 123 </td><td> John Smith </td></tr>
```

My main php page has:

```
<table border='1px'>
<tr><th colspan='6'> <?php echo ($eName . " - " . $vn); ?></th></tr>
<tr><th>Player ID</th>
<th>Player Name</th>
<th>Place</th>
<th>Points</th>
<th>Cash</th>
<th>Ticket?</th></tr>

<tr><td colspan='3'>Search <input type='text' id='newsearch'</input>
</table>
<br>

<div id="newsearch-data"> </div>

<script>
 var players = [];   
</script>    

<?php

//Makes php array into js array
foreach ($_SESSION['players'] as $id){
echo "<script> players.push('" . $id . "') </script>";
}

?>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"> </script>
<script src="global.js"> </script>
```

js page:

```
$('input#newsearch').on('keyup', function(){
    var newsearch = $('input#newsearch').val();
    if ($.trim(newsearch)!= "") {
        $.post('newsearch.php', {newsearch: newsearch}, function(data) {
            $('div#newsearch-data').text(data);
        });
    }
});
```

And 2nd php page

```
<?php
  session_start();
  unset($_SESSION['players']);
if (isset($_POST['newsearch']) === true && empty($_POST['newsearch'] === false)){
require 'dbconnect.php';

$term = $_POST['newsearch'];
$terms = "%" . $term . "%";

$_SESSION['players'] = array();

$query = ("SELECT * FROM players WHERE Username LIKE '$terms'");
$run_query = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);

        while ($dbsearch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query))
         {
         array_push ($_SESSION['players'],$dbsearch['PlayerID']);
           echo "<tr><td>" . $dbsearch['PlayerID'] . "</tr></td>";

         }}?
```

How can I output a new row on a html table rather than raw html code?

Comment: example of typical output:


<tr><td>26</tr></td><tr><td>30</tr></td><tr><td>33</tr></td><tr><td>44</tr></td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace  `$('div#newsearch-data').text(data);`

with  `$('div#newsearch-data').html(data);`

`$.text()` escapes the input string and you should use it when you know the input is a string, and that you want to preset it "as is". If the input includes actual HTML that you want to inject into the DOM, `$.html()` is your friend :-)

Comment: explained :-) @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1):

You need `.html()` to render output as a HTML rather than `.text()`, because `.text()` will output the result as a raw data, then try this solution instead :

```
$('div#newsearch-data').html(data);
```

**[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/hossain/sUTVg/)** -  *credited to @Peter Bailey for live example.*

**References**

1. http://api.jquery.com/html/ - `.html()`
2. http://api.jquery.com/text/ - `.text()`

Comment: Yeah, on the way mate.